# Xpages - Code not executing from radio group due to validators

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a radio group button, on a page, with very simple onChange code (tried with onClick also) which reads:

```
try{
    print("1");
    print("2");
}catch(e){
    openLogBean.addError(e,this.getParent());
}
```

There is a partial refresh with id set to the div containing all my page content. The refresh fires as expected, but the code doesn't run. I have worked out, it is because of validation on other fields, as when I turn validation off for these fields, the code runs.

The question is, how can I get this code to run, whilst leaving validation on for the other fields? I've tried setting `"Do not validate or update data"` and `"Process data without validation"` set on my radio group where I want to fire the code, but no such luck. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems `"Do not validate or update data"` does do the trick, I think my application hadn't built properly first few times around. Leaving here for as an answer for anyone else with similar question

**EDIT:**

As per Paul's comment below `"Process data without validation"` will update the server-side and should be the one to use.

Comment: "Do not validate or update data" won't update the server-side with any content from the browser. So your onchange event won't take into account what's been selected and, if the user has entered anything in the refresh area, it will get overwritten with the defaults. "Process data without validation" will update the server-side and should be the one to use. It will just skip validation. However, it still checks conversion, so if the user puts "One" in a number field, it will still fail validation. So always ensure there's an Errors control in the refresh area.